# Failed values using boost::get

Tags: c++, boost, c++14

All I'm trying to do is understand what this exception means, in general, so I don't want to attach any code to it. Here is the full error:
`libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type boost::wrapexcept<boost::bad_get>: boost::bad_get: failed value get using boost::get`

Answer (score 0):

As the exception says, `boost::get` failed.  The most likely cause is that the `boost::variant` that you're trying to `get` a value from doesn't currently hold the type you're trying to `get`.  For example, the following will throw the exception you're seeing because `foo` currently holds an `int`, not a `double`:

```
int main (){
    boost::variant<int, double> foo;
    foo = 42;
    std::cout << boost::get<double>(foo);
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/04bcfd3e0a8ab2e7)